# How to read variable number of outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running python 2.7.3. I have a list of functions that I invoke each. Some functions return more than one outputs. I'd like to save all the outputs of all functions in a list. How can I do that?

```
def f1():
    return [1,2], [3,4]
def f2():
    return [5,6]
my_outputs = []
my_funcs = [f1, f2]
for func in my_funcs:
    output_list* = func() # does this work?
    # a,b,c... = func()
    my_outputs.extend(output_list)

print my_outputs
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Comment: I'd bet dollars to donuts this is covered in the official tutorial.

Comment: Give it a try and you'll know.

Comment: You mean that you want to *extend* the list when the function returns a sequence, and just append when the function returns just one value?  Functions that return multiple values just return one value really, a *`tuple()`*.

Comment: (Personally I'd just clean up the design so that all the functions return sequences, instead of having different "signatures".)

Comment: @millimoose I cannot clean up the design because it's a library I'm using

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, how can I check that?

Comment: @siamii: You can test if the return value is a tuple: `if isinstance(output, tuple)`; I do wonder what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the return type with `isinstance`, although it's not very pythonic.

```
 my_outputs = []
 my_funcs = [f1, f2, f3]
 for func in my_funcs:
    result = func()
    if isinstance(result, tuple):
        my_outputs.extend(result)
    else:
        my_outputs.append(result)
```

Comment: this appends a tuple to the list

Comment: use my_outputs.extend(func())

Comment: actually, the outputs are always lists, so only need to check for tuple then

Comment: @siamii you're confusing me, if the results are always `tuples` or `lists` you could just use `my_outputs.extend(func())`

Comment: the results are a single list or multiple lists

Answer (score 1):

```
sum((list(f()) for f in [f1, f2]), [])
```